# How to use useNavigate previous page without accidentally leaving my site

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Problem**: I'm trying to use `useNavigate(-1)` to go to previous page, but I just implement a way to people arrive in my SPA with a pasted link (or social media tho), so, when user tries to go back they leave my site xP.

**Process**: I could use `useNavigate("/")`, but this makes my page scroll to the top and I want to keep the previous users position, I rather not use a state with my scroll position, but if nothing else is possible or simple...

**Context**: is a restaurant menu ifood-like page, this problems occurs in product page and I want to go back to product list.

**What I'm trying to achieve**: some way to check if previous page is out of my domain and not go there, replacing with my root.

ps. I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In earlier versions of React Router DOM, [there was a smarter `goBack` method](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/408), but in modern versions (including the v6 beta), you must use the fact that the [`location.key` is `"default"` for the initial entry to the app's history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v5.0.0/docs/api-reference.md#locationkey).

I created an [npm package that encapsulates this functionality in a simple React hook](https://github.com/evelynhathaway/use-back).

### Install use-back

```sh
npm install use-back
```

### Usage

```
import {useBack} from "use-back";

const BackButton = () => {
  const {hasBack, handleBack} = useBack();
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleBack}>
      {hasBack ? "Go Back" : "Go Home"}
    </button>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-6-use-back-2gxln)

### Source Code

The source code is basically the following, which you can also include in your application.

```
const MagicalBack = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const hasPreviousState = location.key !== "default";

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (hasPreviousState) {
      navigate(-1);
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      {hasPreviousState ? "Go Back" : "Go Home"}
    </button>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-6-smart-back-4115q)

Comment: Amazing!! The code worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Also, I turn it in a custom hook and made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usebacksafe-ik66n?file=/src/index.js) like yours to demonstrate it